# String.fromCharCode show different output on different browsers

Tags: javascript, string, browser, fromcharcode

[image: fromCharCode MDN]

[image: chrome devtool]

[image: firefox devtool]

I think these output should be the same.according to https://asecuritysite.com/coding/asc2.

But it displays output differently on different browser.why?

Also it's bad for code like `fromCharCode` running on multiple browser.Function's output is likely different from what you expect.How to prevent it?

Comment: The result is always the same character. How it is displayed in the console (or the DOM) doesn't really matter.

Comment: How did you get `" "` from 0x12, I'm getting the empty string `""` ..?

Comment: @Andreas I think browsers are respect to the standard,there is no argument.But why they display the value like that.Anyway thank you for answering me.

Comment: _"I think browsers are respect to the standard"_ - That would be good, but IE, Safari, ...; _"why they display the value like that"_ - Because the author of that part of function thought it would be a good format for a white-space character when logged in the console.

Comment: @Teemu the MDN screenshot is captured by the latest chrome.I have no idea about the empty string.

Comment: @Andreas this one convinced me a lot.ty!